# how to use function as variable c++

Tags: c++, class, variables, class-variables

I want to create somekind of event system in c++ for my needs

I know that you can use fuction as other function parameter

May be i missed something(But in c# you can do it with events handlers)

Comment: Maybe you are interested in https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/function-pointers.html

Comment: This is a broad question. Have you tried any textbooks? Online tutorials? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer

Comment: Learn about [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming))s, [lambda expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)s, [function object](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional)s. Read [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/) then a good [C++ programming](http://stroustrup.com/Programming/) book

Comment: You can easily pass functions into other functions with `std::function`, but from the design point of view you probably need the observer pattern

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can store it in a pointer.
For example

```
void func(int a) { ... }
void (*ptr)(int) = &func;
(*ptr)(5); // call the function with value 5
```

ptr is a pointer which takes as value a memory of a function that has one 'int' argument and 'void' as return type.

Comment: In C++11, [lambda expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)s are more relevant

Comment: `std::function` objects are much easier.

Comment: @JesperJuhl , what file do i need to include for this?

Comment: @Metal Cat - `<functional>`. As can easily be seen in [the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) .

Comment: works but I get `invalid use of void expression` if I try to reassign ptr to another function.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the "[Observer Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)" (see also [UML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern#/media/File:Observer_w_update.svg)):

Every event listener must be derived from an abstract class (Observer), which contains the event methods. You can implement your specific event listener code in such a derived class. A Subject class contains all the event listener objects (a vector of abstract class Observer) and notifies them in case the event occurs.